# How to parse url and remove specific parameters

Tags: javascript

I would like to parse a url query  string and filter and remove specific parameters.

Say the url is:  www.test.com?id=123&location-texas&color=blue&event=new

And the query string : ?id=123&location-texas&color=blue&event=new

I would like to always remove the parameters id={} and color={}.

The url may or may not contain either id or color params.

The value of those parameters are not always the same but I always want to strip  id and color from the query string.

I tried the following – I believe I am on the right track but need some assistance finishing up

```
  const test = decodeURIComponent(qs.query).split('?')[1].split('&')
      .filter(param => param !== id='123' || param !== color='blue' );
```

I would like to reconstruct the filtered array and make it :
www.test.com?location-texas&event=new

Comment: Did you mean `param !== "id=123"` and `param !== "color=blue"`?

Comment: No. I want to do OR. What if the Url only contains one parameter? I edited the question

Comment: I did not refer to the boolean operator. I refered to the missing quotes around your strings.

Comment: Got it. should include quotes. thats an error on my part

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `replace`

```
query.replace(/(\w+)=\w*/gi, (m, p) => {
  if (p === 'id' || p === 'color') return ''
  return m
})
```

More information about [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Or just use `URLSearchParams` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: I dont think URLSearchParams is compatible with amny browsers. What is the regex function doing here?

Comment: Just find a pattern like key=value then replace to empty or itself.